# Add a spiked end to timber

Tags: wood, woodworking

I can buy tree stakes, which are 32mm x 32mm x 1.2m quite easily. However on occasion I need something slightly thicker, say 50mm x 50mm or 75mm x 75mm but of equal or shorter length (<1.2m), and sometimes I need those tree stakes, but shorter. Used for various things around my allotment, driven into the ground with a lump hammer.

The thicker timber is always flat ended, and never spiked. The thinner timber once cut produces a flat ended off cut. Is there a way, other than manually planing the timber into a point, to create this spike. I almost want a very large pencil sharpener.

What I know I don't want is the metal spikes that are used for fencing, as these are costly and pointless for my applications. I have tried to saw the end into a spike, but as I am unable to do this evenly around the edge when driven into the ground its never straight. The timber is too thick to whittle.

Comment: Which types of woodworking power tools do you possess?

Comment: Fortifying for the zombie apocalypse by chance?

Comment: @statueuphemism you got through my thinly veiled disguise.

Comment: @Harper, power tools is easier to say none. I'd buy the right one though if thats what is suggested.

Comment: many tools would do; it's a question of what other  uses the tool would have for you, once this is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Man using a drawknife on a pole]
[CC BY-SA 3.0 DontWorry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawknife#/media/File:Hessenpark-stockmacher-002.jpg)

You could probably use any of

- hand tools

  - hand axe and stump - and practice.
  - hand saw - and more practice, or a custom mitre-box/jig
  - [drawknife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drawknife)
  - adze - and lots of practice
  - large chisels and mallet?
- power tools

  - band saw
  - table saw with mitre-gauge or jig and clamps
  - chop-saw with jig for angle and external support for stake
  - sabre-saw (reciprocating saw)

For a one-off job I would use a hand saw to make four cuts to produce a point. If it came out off-centre I'd true it up with whatever hand tools I have to hand which worked best (maybe even a jack-plane set up for hogging off). Then keep practising.

I know you really are looking for [a giant pencil sharpener](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hak8RoOnNdY)

See also https://woodworking.stackexchange.com

Comment: I looked through the stack exchange list twice and didn't see woodworking. Obviously looking without seeing. I think 4 saw cuts is the way forward - I hadn't thought of introducing a mitre-box for accuracy. Thanks.